# how to change multiple text on button on button click and how to store that text in database

Tags: android, button, text

This is my code for text change, I need to know how to change multiple text on button on button click and how to store that text in database.  Can anyone help?

```
public void onButtonClick(View v) {
    btn3 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    if ( count==0) {
        btn3.setText("A");
        btn3.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#e20d10"));
        count = 1;
    } else if (count == 1) {
        btn3.setText("L");
        btn3.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0d1be2"));
        count = 2;        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

to save value into db follow this code

```
  SQLiteDatabase db;
db=openOrCreateDatabase("mydb",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
 db.execSQL("create table if not exists table(col_name varchar(20))");
db.execSQL("insert into table values("+bt3.gettext().toString()+")");
```